How can I custom a Jupyter Lab extension's settings UI
When I create a project about Jupyter Lab extension. I can define settings properties at the schema JSON file. But the string property alway show as a input component. Can I define a property field show in settings page use textarea or markdown editor as a markdown cell?
For example. There is a schema JSON:
// ...
    "system": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "System Prompt:",
      "description": "System Prompt would insert into at first of chat messages list with system role.",
      "default": "your are a python and jupyter export"
    }
// ...

The settings page would be:

And I want to the editor for System Prompt is a textarea or markdown editor.
